# React app with WebAssembly is slow in Chrome but fast in Firefox. Why?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, webassembly

I have some sample simulation code written in Rust that compiles to WebAssembly. I've built a small React app that renders data fetched from WebAssembly for each update.

When running this code in Chrome, I observe "pauses" that cause the app to be a bit jittery. Running the app in Firefox is a lot faster and smoother.

[image: chrome-vs-firefox]

(Chrome is on the left, Firefox is on the right)

When I profile the code in Chrome via its developer tools, I see that my code tends to "idle":

[image: chrome-profiler]

Zooming in on a portion of the performance graph where the pause occurs:

[image: zooming-in-on-performance-graph]

Here I can see that the browser is in a state of "Fire Idle Callback" which includes a call into "flushBufferWhileIdle".

Why does this occur in Chrome but not Firefox? Do you have any thoughts on how I can determine whether or not the issue is due to React / JavaScript or WebAssembly?

Thank you!!

Comment: Firstly, what kind of toolchain did you use to compile wasm? Toolchains include browser-specific codes when you compile. While I'm not sure about your specific case yet, [it is widely known that WASM runs much faster on Firefox than on Chrome.](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/a-real-world-webassembly-benchmark/)